# Failed: Installing Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS on External SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

I am experiencing a problem when trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS onto an external SSD. I hope to get help with the following errors:

Thank you.

---

Mission:
To install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS on an External SSD

Hardware to be installed on:
Sabrent USB Type-C Enclosure
Crucial 1TB NVMe M.2 SSD

Installation media:
Sandisk dual USB-C Go flash drive

---

Partitioning scheme as per installation process:
/Boot 100 MB
/Swap area 8,192 MB
/     204,800 MB

---

Errors:
Installed linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic package post-installation script process returned error exit status 1

An error occurred while installing packages:
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The following packages are in a broken state:

This may be due ti using an old installer image , or it may be due to a bug in some of the packages listed above...

---

I have tried it a few times using the option: "download updates" during installation and without the download option.

---

When attempting to boot from the external SSD, the following is printed on-screen:

(See attached image)

[Kernel panic.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcWFl.jpg)

Comment: You've only reported on the end of the error listing; ie. the final summary from the calling routine, not the routine which actually had the error message; so I'd look at all the messages. You often get the option to file a bug, if you did select that; providing the bug ID will allow us to look up details there; as your summary detail is insufficient for me to have any idea.

Comment: What else do you need? I took photos of whatever errors that flashed on screen. I don't recall seeing an option to file a bug either.

Comment: If you think the problem might be from using an old installation image, why haven't you tried one that is up-to-date?

Comment: I think I have the latest iso to begin with. The problem could be just installing on an external ssd that I might not understand what else went wrong.

Comment: After many attempts with limited know-how and trying out different suggestions, I still could not boot from my external SSD. Decided then to try another distro. Selected Fedora 34 and it went through without a single glitch, so I am now using Fedora instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for several days, there seemed to be no more help from this forum.

Still failing to boot from the installed external SSD, I had decided to try a different distro and Fedora 34 was installed.

Fedora 34 installed easily and booted from my external SSD without any issue, so Fedora it is for me and out went Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS as I could not get any help from this community or anywhere so far.

Case closed.